# After svn commit all files have root owner and group

Tags: svn, root

Earlier i worked with my site through FTP client and all my files had owner user_ftp.
Now i use SVN and after commit my files have owner and group root and permission 000.

It's not problem, if i make changes in files from folder controllers, models etc, but when i made changes in file index.php - site give 500 internal server error, and i must manually change owner and group for this file with command

```
chown user_ftp:user_group index.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion does not track permissions in the repository, except for the execute bit. If you have a SVN working copy with files owned by root, that's because you did your `svn checkout` or `svn update` as root. Don't do that; *nothing* in SVN requires root access.

Comment: Thank you, i'm logged as user_ftp and made svn up - all works.